# Push to two remote repositories (backup and staging) individually

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have these two repositories:

**Repository A**

Bitbucket - Remote dev backup - 30+ commits.

**Repository B**

Siteground account - Staging - Initial commit.

I have been working on my framework for a while (+30 commits). Now I have created a subdomain on my Siteground account which will be used as a staging server. Siteground supports git, so I have created a repository in cPanel.

I have then added the Siteground repo as a new remote in Sourcetree. This is what it looks like, right now:

[image]

Now I wan't to push my latest commit to the new Siteground repo and be able to push to both Bitbucket and staging individually from now on.

I have tried just pushing the latest commit to staging, but I get this error:

[image]

I guess there's a problem because the two repos are not related.

**How can I push to two different remote repositories individually?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it using `git pull staging master --allow-unrelated-histories` using the CLI (this feature is not available in the Sourcetree GUI yet) and then just committing and pushing to both remotes. It works.

[image]